# Adding missing records to table Oracle between specified dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table as below :

[image]

But what I want is below output:

[image]

For each name record should be present on each day starting from min.date to max. date. If the record is not present in original table then it's value should be updated as 0 on particular date.

I'm not able to figure out the query for this.
Pls. can anyone could suggest me writing query for this.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have all dates in the table, you can use the data in the original tables.  Use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select n.name, d.date, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct name from t) n cross join
     (select distinct date from t) d left join
     t
     on t.name = n.name and t.date = d.date;
```

If some dates are missing entirely from the table, then you need a calendar table or some sort of CTE to generate all the dates.